# Embedding chaco in GTK

Tags: python, gtk, plot, pygtk, chaco

Embedding Chaco into Qt and Wx seems to be no problem. Does anyone have an example or an idea how to embed Chaco into GTK?

Answer (score 2):

I use python with matplotlib.
To have a graphic inserted in the GUI, I need a "backend" : http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/faq/installing_faq.html#backends

Code snippet :

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_gtkagg import FigureCanvasGTKAgg as Canvas
```

Then, instance it (the add_subplot prepares a place for one plot) :

```
figsn  = matplotlib.pyplot.figure()
ax     = figsn.add_subplot(1,1,1)
canvas = Canvas(figsn)
...
snBox.pack_start(canvas, True, True)
canvas.draw()
```

So, what I want to say is that you need a "backend" from your package where you may be able to draw into, and that GTK can recognize. It suppose your chaco lib has to be compiled with GTK support.
I can not install chaco here today, so please dig that way and let me know what you find !